# What is the "grub prompt"? / unknown prompt

Tags: grub2

I am a entry level person for Ubuntu using 11.10 currently trying to install it on a hdd.

I have a P4 and 10gb hdd totally dedicated to Ubuntu 11.10. I am installing from a DVD. I need to change some grub configuration but am unable to get the grub prompt

As per the graphics it should be something like

```
grub>
```

but all i am getting is

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

What does this ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ prompt stand for?
I got the graphical menu for ubuntu telling me

1. test ubuntu without installing
2. install ubuntu ....
3. memory test etc and
   3 more menus.

I selected install Ubuntu and proceeded but got no grub.

I am totally confused about the grub prompt. I am not getting it and got the above one. . the documentataion says to press esc / right shift key at the time of boot .

Am i expected to press esc key right after the First BIOS beep or the second bios beep or when?? I did not get the grub prompt even after pressing the right shift key after first bios beep.  I am confused about the timing.

When & which key to be pressed and at what time to get the grub prompt???
I have tried various ways to get the grub prompt but i don't get it and eventually I reach the Ubuntu installation menu where I select the install Ubuntu option and after that i press shift Ctrl F1 where i get the above menu.

Also i am getting a boot:  prompt in early stage i do not know about it also what is that prompt

Let me know what key combinations to use and exactly when after the first BIOS beep to get the grub prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$` because your `grub` is set to boot silently.

To change this behaviour, edit `/etc/default/grub` with this command:

```
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change:

```
 GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

to:

```
 GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

for example.

For `GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1`, there will be no countdown and thus the menu will display.
For `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`, menu will not display even for a failed startup.
For `GRUB_TIMEOUT>=1`, menu will display for the specified number of seconds.

Run `sudo update-grub` after the change have been made and reboot. Now you will get a X seconds of timeout before booting.

Comment: Also i am getting a boot:  prompt in early stage i do not know about it also what is that prompt

Comment: Hi Frantique , Thank you for the suggestion Please note  that i am using dvd for installation. with boot sequence of DVD - hdd after rebooting the entire procedure starts allover again without the changes done. the sudo update-grub do not work it refused to save the changes. any suggestion for the situation. Am i supposed to remove the DVD after rebooting ????   Also i am getting a           boot:      prompt in early stage if i press esc button. i do not know about it also what is that prompt

Comment: @ulka: Did you installed the system, or you are just trying to run it from DVD? I think you should read carefully the first steps in running Ubuntu. You will find a lot of info here: http://help.ubuntu.com

Comment: Hi Frantique , Thank you for your advice. I have decided to install ubuntu 12.10 from pendrive. I have downloaded the iso and trying to install. BUT currently i am stuck up at how to make pendrive bootable. i am using XP for all the operations. It seems the pendrive has to be made bootable and then the .iso to be installed on it. I am using utility from http://www.pendrivelinux.com to install .iso. it is working !! but after trying to boot from USB it is telling non bootable drive. So i am stuck up at the issue 'HOW to make ubuntu  bootable stick' from xp ?? can you give suggestions

Comment: Hi Frantique, Thank you for your advice. I am using ubuntu 12.10 from pendrive. I have iso and trying to install it on pendrive. BUT i am stuck up at **how to make pendrive bootable for 12.10**. i am using XP for all changes. It seems the pendrive has to be made bootable first and then .iso will be installed on it. I am using utility from http://www.pendrivelinux.com to install .iso. on pendrive it is working !! but it is making non bootable USB, as PC is telling it non bootable drive. So i am stuck up at the issue **'HOW to make ubuntu  bootable stick'** from xp ?? can you give suggestions

Comment: What is the problem with your DVD media? You have it, isn't?

Comment: installation is getting hang due to out of frequency error. so I have to change the grub settings and reboot. so i was planning to get bootable usb stick .

Comment: Hi i have got access to machine having ubuntu 7.04 installed on it can i use it for making bootable pendrive. I did not see any startup disc creator prompt on it. any other way to do it on 7.04

Comment: Hi  Frantique My apologies, the MD5 sum is incorrect for the .iso, and i will have to download it again. i will post if some issues come up hang up  till sunday